# Symfony2 - Doctrine:generate:crud - Routing error

Tags: caching, routes, crud, symfony

I'm using Symfony2 RC3 and I have a NewsBundle that has an Article entity.

I generated crud for it using the command: $ php app/console doctrine:generate:crud (with 'write' set to yes).

Now, every page on my site throws this error:

```
Fatal error: Label 'not_admin_article_create' already defined in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/AIEF/app/cache/prod/appprodUrlMatcher.php on line 260
```

If i get rid of

```
requirements: { _method: post }
```

for admin_article_create, admin_article_update and admin_article_delete in the generated routing yml file, everything works fine. Any idea why ?

Comment: Have you tried to clear your server cache (empty app/cache) ?

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue recently, Google search wasn't much help but give me ideas of where to look, anyways enough blah blah.

The error I was getting was as follows:

`` enter code here`Fatal error: Label 'not _ offering management' already defined in /... ``

Whats I noticed was that there was a duplicate entry in **routing_dev.yml** and **routing.yml**, so basically the issue pops up when you happen to have multiple configurations. I think Symfony2 bundle generation adds mapping, but user probably accidental re-configures mapping else where.